# What is the name of the logical equivalence $p\land\neg p\equiv\bot$?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

The conjunction of any statement $p$ by its negation is a contradiction. That is:
$$p\land\neg p\equiv\bot$$
Do you know if there is a name for this logical equivalence?

Comment: I think this is a version of the negation law if that helps? $p \wedge \neg p \equiv F$, I’m not sure if this specific interpretation has a name however, outside of the definition of contradiction.

Comment: Cf. [law of noncontradiction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The non-contradiction is ⊤
. The non-contradiction law is more suitable for ¬(p∧p)≡⊤
. Can we call it law of contradiction instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen both of the following logical equivalencies referred to as *negation laws*:

$$ p \wedge \neg p \equiv \bot $$
$$ p \vee \neg p \equiv \top $$

You can find this on page $29$ of [Discrete Mathematics and its Applications](https://github.com/ccy05327/DM?tab=readme-ov-file), 8th edition, by Kenneth H. Rosen. Below is an excerpt of Table $6$ from page $29$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is really a consensus on what it is called.  The name I most often see is Complement (and that is also how I personally refer to this principle):

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, I have seen Inverse a number of times as well:

[image]

And from the Comments and other Answers, apparently there are other names as well.

Comment: Thank you so much would u plz put few reference books too for the tables?

Answer (score 0):

This is the [law of non-contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction).

Non-contradiction is usually presented as: $$\lnot(p\land\lnot p).$$  But $\lnot x$ is just an abbreviation for $x\to\bot$, so this is identical in meaning to $$(p\land\lnot p)\to \bot$$ which is almost exactly what you asked about.  The other direction, $\bot \to \ldots$, is trivially true, because $\bot\to x$ for all $x$.

Comment: The non-contradiction is $\top$. The non-contradiction law is more suitable for $\neg(p\land p)\equiv \top$. Can we call it law of contradiction instead?

Comment: It's not called the law of non-contradiction because of the symbol on the right side. It's called the law of non-contradiction because a proposition $p$ and the contradictory proposition $\neg p$ cannot both be true. The name "law of non-contradiction" better conveys the concept captured in the law.